# Is there an affordable and flexible API dash button for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: usb

I was wondering if there was a generic dash button for Raspberry Pi. I want to program button press to do something (programming language doesn't matter for me). It would mostly communicate to my cloud through HTTP.

Amazon dash button is very rigid, meaning you have to use AWS APIs to integrate with and I don't want to invest my time in trying to "hack" it to do otherwise.

Comment: Have you considered rolling your own with a button connected to the GPIO pins and a program you right or that uses if this then that (ifttt.com).

Answer (score 3):

There is a [nodeMCU](http://nodemcu.com/index_en.html) based related project listed on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NodeMCU#The_Button) that features exactly what you ask for:

> The Button is design for single-purpose, internet-enabled functions. When the button is pressed, a connection is made to a web server which will perform the desired task.

An alternative might be [ParticleIO](http://www.particle.io).